# How to include a dictionary into a k8s_raw data field

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, ansible-template

I'm writing an ***Ansible-playbook*** to insert a list of secret object into Kubernetes.
I'm using ***k8s_raw*** syntax and I want to import this list from a ***group_vars*** file. 
I can't find the right syntax to import the list of secret into my data field.

## playbook.yml

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Create a Secret object
    k8s_raw:
      state: present
      definition:
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Secret
        data:
          "{{ secrets }}"
          SKRT: "c2trcnIK"
        metadata:
          name: "test"
          namespace: "namespace-test"
        type: Opaqueroot
  vars_files:
    - "varfile.yml"
```

## varfile.yml

```
secrets:
  TAMAGOTCHI_CODE: "MTIzNAo="
  FRIDGE_PIN: "MTIzNAo="
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the ***SKRT: "c2trcnIK"*** field just under the ***"{{ secrets }}"*** line. I deleted it and now it works ! Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

First, what does it actually say when you attempt the above? It would help to have the result of your attempts.

Just guessing but try moving the var_files to before the place where you try to use the variables. Also, be sure that your indentation is exactly right when you do.

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - /varfile.yml

  tasks:
  - name: Create a Secret object
    k8s_raw:
      state: present
      definition:
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Secret
        data:
          "{{ secrets }}"
        metadata:
          name: "test"
          namespace: "namespace-test"
        type: Opaqueroot
```

[Reference](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-in-files)

side note: I would debug this immediately without attempting the task. Remove your main task and after trying to use vars_files, attempt to directly print the secrets using the `debug` play. This will allow you to fine tune the syntax and keep fiddling with it until you get it right without having to run and wait for the more complex play that follows. [Reference](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html#debug-module).

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

> To import this list from a group_vars file

Put the *localhost* into a group. For example a group *test*

```
> cat hosts
test:
  hosts:
    localhost:
```

Put the *varfile.yml* into the *group_vars/test* directory

```
$ tree group_vars
group_vars/
├── test
    └── varfile.yml
```

Then running the playbook below

```
$ cat test.yml
- hosts: test
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: secrets.TAMAGOTCHI_COD

$ ansible-playbook -i hosts test.yml
```

gives:

```
PLAY [test] ***********************************
TASK [debug] **********************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "secrets.TAMAGOTCHI_CODE": "MTIzNAo="
}
PLAY RECAP *************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```